# VueJS CDN import error. Uncaught TypeError. Vue Component is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to run this Reddit clone.

I imported different types of Vue CDNs,

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Vue.component is not a function"
```

I'm not sure if I'm importing the wrong version of Vue, or if I have the wrong settings on jsfiddle.

```
var subreddit = Vue.component('subreddit',{
template: '#subreddit',
props: ['name'],

data: function () {
    return { posts: [] }
},

created: function(){
    this.$http.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/"+ this.name +"/top.json?limit=3")
    .then(function(resp){
        this.posts=resp.data.data.children;
    });
}
});
```

Full code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/jm0vs2kn/22/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is pointing on the Vue version 3 `@next` which has some breaking changes in global API, to work with Vue 2 use the following [CDN](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN) :

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

You should also create a div inside the document `body` like `<body><div id="app"></div> ...` then mount the vue app like `new Vue({el: '#app'});`

Your [x-templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#X-Templates) should be defined outside the `div` with id `app` as follows :

```
 <script type="text/x-template" id="subreddit">
        <div class="subreddit">
            <h2>{{ name | uppercase }}</h2>
            <ul class="item-list">
                <li v-for="obj in posts">
                    <post :item="obj"></post>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </script>
```

`<div id="#app">` should be `<div id="app">`

and `.then(function(resp){` should be an arrow function `.then((resp)=>{`

The example below uses `axios` to make ajax calls.

[LIVE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/de1972xo/5/)

Comment: create a div inside the document `body` like `<body><div id="app"></div> ...` then mount the vue app like `new Vue({el: '#app'});`

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I had the div id wrong, among other things. It's my first week with Vue.

Comment: I realized the JSON from the Reddit API still isn't loading. The full app should look like this: https://demo.tutorialzine.com/2016/08/building-your-first-app-with-vue-js/

Comment: you could use axios to fetch data https://jsfiddle.net/de1972xo/5/

Comment: That's working now, good. I'll accept the answer if you add the axios info. Hope it helps someone.